# Which setting allows user to only view major versions?

Tags: 2013, permissions

I'm filling in for our SP admin, who is unreachable, and can't figure out which permission level I need to assign so that a group of users only see major versions of documents.

Apparently someone who should only be able to see major versions has been able to see a minor version of a document on our SharePoint site (They saw v1.11). It could be that the offending content was part of 1.0 thus permissions aren't the real issue but I'm investigating this as a first step.

AFAIK I would be applying the permissions to entire folders and not to particular documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SP.SE Vidro3!

This is not a permissions issue - its a versioning setting in the document library. 
You basically have 2 options:

1. Only users who can edit items (contribute rights).
2. Only users who can approve items (and the AUTHOR of the item).

Comment: So it's Library settings>Versioning Settings> and Draft Item security, right?
And that is effective for the entire Library, in other words the entire folder hierarchy - and cannot be set to a different option at different levels in the hierarchy, right?
Thanks

Comment: Correct. You could give different people different rights in the hierarchy. Combined with the versioning settings you can pretty much control everything.